# Complexity of merge operation in merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort, array-merge

I'm reading Cormen's Introduction into algorithms.
I can't understand why merging `n/k` arrays with `k` elements in each of them has the complexity of `O(n*log(n/k))`.
What I'm missing here is that we have `n/k` arrays. Therefore, we have to perform the merge `n/(k-1)` times each with `O(n)` upper-bound.
However we have a logarithm, so I suppose that I'm missing something in my understanding of Merge complexity.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you only can merge two arrays with merge(a,b), then you can build a "tree" of merges:

```
a    b      c     d
  ab           cd
       abcd
```

Now, it is true that using this operation you are doing indeed `n/k - 1` merges - but note that most of them are done with few elements, significantly less than `n` elements per array.

If you calculate it carefully, you'll get:

```
2*(n/k)/2 * k + 2*(n/k)/4 * 2k + .... + 1*n
```

If you do the algebra, you'll note that this is indeed `n*log(n/k)`.

---

As a side not, another way to do k-way merge is to hold a heap of size `n/k`, and let it hold the smallest number from each array that was not exhausted yet, and while iterating - get the smallest element in the heap to the result array.

Comment: I have just realized it. Thanks.

Comment: But wouldn't the constant be a bit higher if we use heap because when inserting it's possible to have several swaps?

Comment: @LongSmith Heap data structure got good locality of reference property, which means it is pretty cache friendly. It will depend on machine and specific scenarios, but I believe it will have better constants for most implementation because of it.